# Does using require() has impact on the performance?

Tags: node.js, dependency-management

When a module is required in node.js two times it gives back the same object because `require()` cache the previous calls.

How fast is the second require? Could the continuous-use of `require()` cause a perfomance bottleneck?

So lets say I have a module like this:

```
var util = require("util");

module.exports = function (param, logger) {
var module = {};

module.toString = function() {
    return util.format("My nicely formatted text");
}

return module;
```

};

The `toString()` will be called multiple times. What happens if I omit the saving of the util module in the `util` variable and require it everytime, like this:

```
return require("util").format("My nicely formatted text");
```

Does this make my application slower?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calls to `require()`  are cached, so there shouldn't be a very big difference between the two. However, I would recommand loading all your modules at the top of the file. The startup of your application will be slightly slower, but it shouldn't make a very big difference anyways, and it's more readable.

Also, calls to `require()` are blocking, so when they are processed nothing else is being run by Node. That's another reason why you should put all your requires at the top, so you don't end up blocking your application further down the road.